# Access token based server client communication

Tags: authentication, security, encryption, access-token

I am currently working on a private project using a client-server communication via TCP.
I have implemented a Two Sides Challenge Response algorithm as authentication mechanism, so both the server and the client can validate their identity. After this validation step the server issues an access token to the client.
How would I proceed from there down the line to enable communication without risking attacks?
The token could be embedded in every message exchanged between the client and the server, but therefor could be copied by an attacker and used to send messages without authenticating itself to the server.
In my mind the only secure way would be to hash the token with a different salt on each interaction which would result in a large programming overhead and provides its own issues with asynchronous communication from multiple threads (Keeping track of the salt to use, ...)
I did not find much information on handling access tokens in this kind of scenario.
Maybe a token based authorization may also be the wrong approach and I am open for suggestions for alternative mechanisms.

**Edit for additional information on the scenario:**
The communication is already protected by TLS with unique certificates for every device. Within the network of devices there can be multiple "sessions" (servers with clients connected to them). These sessions should be protected by passwords, so they could only be joined when clients know the password. The token should then serve as proof of authentication.

Is there a existing solution for handling such a authentication process?

Comment: _"The token could be embedded in every message exchanged between the client and the server, but therefor could be copied by an attacker and used to send messages without authenticating itself to the server"_ - that's what TLS is for

Comment: Three things - use TLS, don't reinvent REST/HTTP, don't implement your own authentication. You break one of the rules, your system will be broken into.

Comment: I am already using TLS on the underlaying sockets with unique certificates for every participant. So this would mean if I would ensure that each certificate can only be used for one concurrent connection to the server (by manually checking the certificates) I would be fine?

Comment: Yes, though the requirement to have at most one concurrent connection per cert at most is awkward. You may have network issues cause problems like client being disconnected, server believing the session is still open and the client unable to reconnect.